# What happens if you buy 3 Greyhound tickets for yourself (in the US) that you swipe your card at the kiosk to print out?

Tags: usa, buses, greyhound

Could you get less than 3? That would be bad. I want to get to DC 2 hours before my second ticket. I also want to buy my trip out of DC as two separate tickets because it's cheaper even though it's the exact same itinerary as a direct ticket. Would this cause any problems?

Comment: Is your question "Will the ticket printer work correctly?"

Comment: adding USA tag as this system doesn't exist in Greyhound Australia last I checked.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure the programmer had thought someone might have three un-picked up transactions before (not 3 tickets — I'm sure the machine knows what to do if you clicked 2 adults and 1 kid on one transaction). Most people probably just print them or pay full price but I don't have a printer. I don't have 3 cards to use one for each ticket either which would make me stop worrying.

Comment: I don't see even a question here. You bought 3 tickets? And what is the problem with having 3 tickets for a trip with 3 legs? And what's up with kiosks? There are kiosks to print Greyhound tickets? For me this lacks context and a clear question.

Comment: No problem with 3 legs. I guess that was irrelevant info, (though it does tell you that I probably wouldn't be breaking against any rules they might have on too little time to transfer). Yes there's been kiosks in major stations for many years. That's where they tell you to pick up Will Call tickets bought online (the other option is printing, but I don't want some damn fool smartphone or connection problem interfering anyway). The kiosk tells you to swipe the card you used to buy online which makes me worried as they didn't make it clear that you'd get more than just the most recent purchase.

Comment: And then there's the whole other question of whether two hours in DC is enough time. Your bus into DC will probably be late, and you will probably miss your connection. (Though this isn't usually a big deal; you just get on the next bus.)

Comment: That's okay, it's a just a 4 hour detour to make me arrive at a good time without waking up at a god awful hour just to transfer. There might even be time to take the Metro to see something on a bucket list for 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the system will know you have separate reservations, as each time you book, you should get a confirmation number and each will be different.  The ticketing kiosk will look up the tickets to print based on your confirmation number, which will be also tied to the card you used.  It is not uncommon for people to book multiple tickets.

And in worst case scenario, you go talk to the ticket agent at the bus station before your bus gets there and have them look up your booking(s).  Of course this may result in the agent seeing your "hidden city" ticketing trick, though I am not sure if Greyhound has policies against this like the airlines do.